# Numeral Formatting on amounts

Tags: javascript, numeral.js

I use NumeralJS for formatting amounts as below;

```
numeral(unformattedValue).format(amtFormat)
```

Now if the amtFormat is set as "0,0.00", then if the amount is entered as "123.1", I get it as "123.10"

Now I have certain cases where I do not want to apply any formatting (i.e. after the decimal)...So in the above example, if user enters "123.1", I should get same "123.1"
Is it possible to somehow set the "amtFormat" to something which can give me that ?

So it is probably like not running the above code itself. But for some reasons (there is other common logic running as well including thousands/pre-decimal other formatting), I want to set the "amtFormat" explicitly which does nothing post decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this link for the javascript

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"

And test like this, 
  var amt = '0, 0.00';
  console.log(numeral(123.1).format(amt));

And in console, it shows 123.10.

Can you try with the numberal.js with given link?

Comment: Thanks....But when I tried....seeing slightly different output here
https://jsbin.com/bemodanuqo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: So...what I want is 123.1 should stay as it is i.e. 123.1 (Anything after the decimal should stay as it is)

Comment: Well, when i access to there, it shows like this 

http://prntscr.com/t0vr6k

Comment: what about browser? i am using google chrome. if it is not working, then i think it would be the browser problem.